# F# Reflection on types created with TypeProvider

Tags: reflection, f#, type-providers

I've created multiple types with type providers, these are used to create record types.
In the next stage of my project, I want to use reflection to build these records. But the problem here is that every type that's created now has the type of System.Object.

So for example, all the members have a type provider type. (Minlength,Email and Required are all type providers I created).

```
type UserT = {
       Name: MinLength
       email : Email
       password : Required
       }
```

when I late use reflection on this i get the following result

```
val refl : PropertyInfo [] =
[|System.Object Name; System.Object email; System.Object password|]
```

Is it possible to use reflection to get the correct type of these members?

thx!

Comment: Type providers come in two flavors: "erasing" and "non-erasing". Only types provided by the latter will be present at runtime.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin thanks, I'll look into these types and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: If you ask an instance of `Email` you should get it's underlying type. However as Fyodor says most type providers uses type erasure meaning that even though it looks like it's statically typed the email property is actually a field of `obj` as you noticed: There are some details on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tutorials/type-providers/creating-a-type-provider

Comment: Generative type providers contain indeed more information, and provide me with most things I need to get further with my project